# Wordpress link change

Tags: woocommerce

I need to modify the structure of the links in woocommerce. In this moment as you may no the link is http://yourwebsite.com/product/name_of_the_product...and I want to change the product in category, the link should be this http://yourwebsite.com/category/name_of_the_product...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say not to change /product/ to /category/ for woocommerce. By Default WordPress use category taxonomy to display category page e.g example.com/category/xyzcategory/. Also change of woocommerce fixed urls can be problem for shop. WooCommerce also advise not to change those https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/